# Google docs not sending notification

Tags: google-drive

Does anyone know why I do not get a notification when someone changes the shared document? My Notification settings are set as below (* means it's set):

```
   Don't send me any email notifications for this doc (not recommended)
 * Enable email notifications for this document's threads

 * Notify me of all new comments and replies on this document
 * Notify me of replies to my comments
 * Notify me of replies to threads that I have commented on
 * Notify me when I am @ mentioned in a comment
```

Answer (score 5):

Those settings are not for notifying you when the document changes. They are for notifying you when ***comments*** on the document change.

You can subscribe to changes in a spreadsheet (on the `Tools` menu), but you cannot (yet) subscribe to changes in a document.

There are add-ons that claim to provide this functionality but I have never used and cannot recommend any of them.